# How to deploy C# exe with .Mdf file?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, mdf

I have created windows application and i have created local database and added user name and password

If username and password is correct then i have to open the code.

I have generated a Setup.Msi , but when i try to install in my machine its working correctly

But when i try to install the same exe in some other machine which is not having .Net or anything related to sql server ..

It shows errors..it cant able to read .Mdf file...How to do it please. help me in this

```
 <add key="Connection" value="Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Download\Test.mdf;Integrated Security=True;"/>
```

Even i tried Integrated security as false .. still the same issue ...

Comment: Create an MSI that installs the prerequisites or check for their existence and ask the users to install them before installing your application

Comment: Can you provide me any link please !!

Comment: i have added it is it legal that can we add prerequisites with our msi for offline installation .. ? @ panagiotis